# Get subquery value in main query

Tags: sql

I am using the below query to get the customer detail. But it's not working please help me. I am new for SQL.

```sql
select cu.fld_cust_id,ord.* from test1 where fld_order_id ord in (select * from tbl_customer cu where cu.fld_status=1);
```

Comment: can you specify exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't select columns from subquery used in `WHERE` clause, becaused they are not joined to this query. You are just using value range returned from this subquery
2. Your subquery should return only one column here.
3. You should try something like this.

   SELECT cu.fld_cust_id,ord.*
   FROM test1 
   JOIN tbl_customer cu ON cu.fld_status=1 AND fld_order_id = cu.fld_cust_id

Comment: fld_order_id = cu.fld_cust_id doesn't make sense, neither does ord.*

Comment: You're right, but we actually don't know how the tables look like.

Answer (score 0):

In a query you also need to be aware that you can only see the fields in the current scope. So in the main query you only use FROM TEST1, therefore you can only see the fields from that table. ord.* and the use of cu will give an error. If you need other fields from that table use a JOIN. The TEST1 table should contain a foreign key that links to TBL_CUSTOMER, if not you need either a path using other other tables or redesign your database. If you have that foreign key, that's what you use around the IN operator:

```
select fld_cust_id from test1 where fld_cust_id in (select id from tbl_customer cu where cu.fld_status=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's in your tbl_customer, but seems like you are matching the fld_order_id to *. You should match with the order_id in your customer table.

```
select cu.fld_cust_id,ord.* 
from test1 
where fld_order_id ord in (
  select *ORDERID* from tbl_customer cu where cu.fld_status=1
);
```